# Userforms resize snaps to arbitrary grid size

Tags: excel, grid, userform

I'm trying to design a Userform in Excel 2010, and I'm coming across a very annoying stumbling block where as I'm trying to move things around, resize them and align them so the form looks appealing.

Unfortunately, different mechanisms are snapping to differently sized grids. For example, drawing a box onto the grid snaps it to multiples of 6, which is the default option found in the Tools> Options> General> Grid units. Resizing these objects snaps it to a seemingly arbitrary grid size that seems to be approximately 7.2 units.

I need these units to match up so I'm not constantly fighting myself getting these grids to function. I don't care what the actual number ends up being, I just need them to be the same. While I'm able to change the grid size, it must be a whole number, which the arbitrary grid is not.

Comment: Try pressing SHIFT or CTRL or ALT when resizing things. In many MS application one of these disables auto snap and allows pixel-level resizing.

Comment: The thing is, I do still want it to snap - I just want it to snap to the same grid as everything else, instead of a seemingly arbitrary one. For now I'm just typing in numbers for size and location, but this seems like a really unnecessary headache, when I should just be able to click and drag.

Comment: I understand but, apparently, it is not possible to change the grid size for auto snapping. I agree, it is quite annoying, but that is one of the things Microsoft imposes and only God knows what their reasons are.

Comment: By the way, I don't recall if it exists, but in some environments you have the possibility to **align** graphical objects. Check if this is available as it may solve your problem (at least partially).

Comment: Damn... That's really weird. I talked to my company's Tech Dude and he said he didn't know any way either, and also that Access DID work with snapping correctly. I basically just typed in the height/width/top/left numbers to align them the way I felt was right. I just wish it could snap that way. I'm better with click and drag than typing out. Less mistakes that way, as a visual person.

Comment: Well my friend, I don't know what your past experience is with programming, but this feeling of disappointment/dissatisfaction is an integral part of our lives, specially when you don't understand why the designer of a tool took certain decisions (like in your case). On the other hand, we do get a lot of satisfaction from time to time. Last, and since my comment is in fact the answer (not the one you wanted, but the answer), I'd appreciate if you up-vote it.

Comment: One more thing (probably you already found it, but I'm adding it in case you didn't): suppose you want to have several labels (or any other type of object) left aligned (i.e. all of them starting at the same offset from the left edge), you can select them all using SHIFT-CLICK and then type for all of them the same offset value. The same for alignments to other directions (up/right/bottom), widths, height,... all graphical properties. Simple trick that helps in situations like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Problem us your units Points <-> Pixels

6 Points  * 4/3 points per pixel =>>  8 Pixels  .. all good
A nice integer of pixels

Your approx 7.2 I suspect was 7.3333333
Maybe say 11 Points Set  gets changed as
 * 4/3 => 14.6666  pix  Rounded to 15   pix
by 3/4 Pts/pix  +> 11.33333
Points as single  .. Pixels as integer may be the problem in the math